# Mulitple records in a single form

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I need to write a page that can takes multiple personal infos. A client will fill in several records of personal info then submit them all at once.

I would like the page to display the input fields for one record at a time only. After filling one record, the client can click a 'Next' button to move on to the next record.

I am thinking to write one form with array input and using javascript to hide/show each record. But this solution seems quit messy, esp. when the number of records is not known. 
Is it possible to nest input fields of each record to a  or table cell and hide/show this element ? The number of input fields in each record is quite large.

I dont want to submit each record since they can include images and all share some common hidden values.

I am sure someone has this problem before, any suggestion for a neat solution ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

considering you have html like this

```
<form>
<table id="page-1">
  <input type="text" name="name"/>
  <input type="text" name="surname"/>
</table>
<table id="page-2">
     <input type="text" name="age"/>
</table>
<div id="page-3">
     <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</div>
</form>
<input id="next" type="button" value="Next"/>
```

so you can do it with simply javascript like this

```
    var actualPage = 0;
    $("#next").click(function() {
        $("#page-" + actualPage).hide();
        actualPage++;
        if(!$("#page-" + actualPage).length) {
             // this was last page
             $(this).hide();
             return false;
        }
        $("#page-" + actualPage).show();
    });
```

there are really numerous ways to do this, i dont know which one depending on what you provided will fit you best

this way javascript doesnt care about how much fields you have and submitting a form will work as expected

Answer (score 0):

From the usability standpoint it's not a good idea. The user is oblivious of the length of the form and have no way of knowing the total steps and how many steps are left.

But lets say that it's a short form and you give the user some kind of cue of the current/total steps.

Yo should display the entire form and use fieldset tags to separate the different steps.
Then use javascript to hide all but the first fieldset and provide a "next step" button
When the user clicks "next step" you should

1. Validate the input
2. Hide the fieldset
3. Show the next one
4. Update the indicator of current/total steps

The validation is important because if there are several invalid inputs, you will not be able to show all the errors at the same time.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't make it clear in my post. The input fields of each step are the same. I want to collect multiple persons info. So the number of step is the number of persons. So first the client will fill info for person_1, click next, fill info for person_2 , etc.

Comment: And you want to make a single submit or one submit for each person?

Comment: I would like to have a single submit , so a single form has to hold information for all persons and this form must spread out to several pages which is displayed one at a time. If that makes sense. Thank .

Comment: You will have to use inputs in form of arrays and whatever server side language you are using must be capable of processing it. Besides that, the concept stills the same. Put the fields for every person in it's own fieldset and hide/show as necessary.